# Accessing IBOoutlet UIButton of different class ios

Tags: ios

How can we access UIButton of other class. i.e. We have a class A and Button ButtonA . When ButtonA clicked then it will add a SubView ViewB on App Delegate Window . Now when Somebody clicks ButtonB on ViewB then i want to change ButtonA image?

How can i do that?

Class B is singleton class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to make accessible `Class A` from `Class B`, you have lots of options, for instance some of them:

- Declare a `Class A` instance variable in your `Class B`, and assign it when creating `class B` from `Class A`.
- Declare a callback block (as instance variable) in `Class B` to be called when `Button B` is clicked.
- From `Class A` listen to a `NSNotification` that posted by `Class B`.
- Implement `KVO` from `Class A` to `Class B's Button B` to listen for changes on it.

Answer (score 1):

There are tons of ways, but if you're using IB:

You should have a property in class B like:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIViewController* classAInstance;
```

assign in in IB to desired class a instance just like ohter stuff

and from class B:

```
self.classAInstance.ButtonB // is accessable
```

To have autocomplete working and avoid compile errors you'll want to `#import classA.h` in classB.

If you don't want to use IB you may do this programmatically(but you'll need to store reference to ClassA instance in ClassB and vice versa anyway), like:

```
classB.classAInstance = classAInstance;
classA.classBInstance = classBInstance;
```

don't forget to also to nil the properties, or they may lock each other (so they won't dealloc).

Comment: How can i access IBOutlet classAinstance from class B? These two are separate classes. How can i attach iboutlet from class B that does not exist?

Comment: I still can't get what's the problem. If you don't have desired classes in IB you may add them (drag Object from objects pallete(where you have buttons, labels, etc) and change it's class to ClassA or whatever), or do that programmatically. The main thing is that you need to store pointer to other class instance.