# call method in UIButton Action in another class

Tags: objective-c, ios, uibutton

I have one class `UIViewController` and Inside I have one button , I want to call one method from another class 
would you please help me to implement the action for my button

I'm new to objective-c

my button Action in `UIViewController`:

```
- (IBAction)ActionButton:(id)sender {
NSLog(@"A1");


}
```

my method in `WebViewControlle`r:

```
    -(void)loadWebView{

    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[ [ NSBundle mainBundle ] pathForResource:  
    @"TestName/TestName1/Test1Name1" ofType:@"html" ]];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [webView loadRequest:request];

   }
```

my question is how to call this method to my button since it's in another view?
I have one method in my `WebViewController` and I want to call it from one button that I have in `UIViewController`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this:

Say you have a class called `ViewA` which implements the method.

If you want the button action to invoke that method, you need to have an instance of another class.

```
-(void)loadWebView{

NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[ [ NSBundle mainBundle ] pathForResource:  
@"TestName/TestName1/Test1Name1" ofType:@"html" ]];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[webView loadRequest:request];

}
```

For you button VIEW:

```
#import "ViewA.h"

ViewA *instanceOfViewA;
// assign an instance to instanceOfViewA
```

Your Button method:

```
- (IBAction)ActionButton:(id)sender {
NSLog(@"A1");
    [yourButton addTarget:instanceOfViewA
                  action:@selector(loadWebView)
        forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

}
```

Comment: I create my button via interface not programmatically

Comment: Not a good solution, loadWebView will be called only when user taps on the button twice or more.

Comment: @MANIAK_dobrii so what it the best ?

Comment: @Superman would please check my post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12917561/call-html-pages-located-different-folder-via-uibutton-objective-c

Answer (score 0):

You may store a reference to WebViewController in your main view controller and send a message to that reference, check my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12910702/accessing-ibooutlet-uibutton-of-different-class-ios/12910804#12910804).

code:

in `MyViewController.h`:

```
@class WebViewController;
...
@interface MyViewController
{
    ...
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet WebViewController* webViewController;
...
```

in `MyViewController.m`:

```
#import "WebViewController.h"
...
@implementation MyViewConroller
@synthesize webViewController;

...
- (void) dealloc {
    ...
    self.webViewController = nil;
    ...
    [super dealloc];
}
```

Assign your WebViewController (like you did with buttons and stuff) in IB and then in code:

```
- (IBAction)ActionButton:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"A1");
    [self.webViewController loadWebView];
}
```

Comment: would you please write the code what do you mean , I have one method in my WebViewControllerand I want to call it from one button that I have in UIViewController

Comment: What error? Seems you did something wrong or I made a typo here (can't see anything for now)

Comment: no visible interface for WebViewController declared the selector 'loadWebView'

Answer (score 0):

You can use notification or delegate or have the reference of WebViewController in your UIViewController ..