# Call html pages located different folder via UIbutton objective-c

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad, uibutton

I have one page with 4 buttons, it's `UIViewController`, and in my application I have 4 folder that inside of each folder I have one html file , I have another `webViewController` that I should load this html files inside of that `webViewController`, I mean when click on first button load first html , if click second load second html and ....
would you please help me to implement this:

here is my method :

```
-(void)loadWebView{

NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[ [ NSBundle mainBundle ] pathForResource:  
@"TestName/TestName1/Test1Name1" ofType:@"html" ]];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[webView loadRequest:request];
}
```

How can I put address like this to my method

```
@"TestName/TestName1/Test1Name1" 

 I mean @"TestName%d/TestName%d/Test%dName" ofType:@"html"
```

and set action to my button to when click on first button goes to first Folder 1 and load html 
when click on second button goes to second Folder 1 and load html and so on ...

here is my buttons

```
- (IBAction)ActionButton1:(id)sender {
NSLog(@"A1");
[self.webViewController loadWebView];
}

- (IBAction)ActionButton2:(id)sender {
NSLog(@"A1");
[self.webViewController loadWebView];
}
```

.
.
.
.

Thanks in advance!

Edit:

File structure folder

```
TestName1

     TestName1

        TestName1.html
```

Second

```
TestName2

     TestName2

        TestName2.html
```

Comment: do your html file have filenames? then what are they?

Comment: @Superman this in my html file Test1Name1.html ,Test1Name2.html inside folder just 1 min I will update the question in Edit part

Answer (score 0):

Just add a parameter to your `loadWebView` method (an int) and create the file path accordingly...

Something like

```
-(void)loadWebView:(int)htmlNum{

    NSString *htmlPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"TestName/TestName%d/Test%dName%d",htmlNum,htmlNum,htmlNum];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:htmlPath ofType:@"html"]];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [webView loadRequest:request];
}
```

You then create a method for your buttons that calls it properly (assigning a tag to your buttons for example could really simplify your code : one method for all buttons...)

```
- (IBAction)ActionButton:(UIButton*)sender {
    [self.webViewController loadWebView:sender.tag];
}
```

Comment: what is htmlNum,htmlNum,htmlNum

Comment: the parameter passed to your `loadWebView` method

Comment: I have error for this webViewController property not found in object class of webViewController what should I add in my header file ?

Comment: sorry for lots of question but how buttons know when button press load which html?

Comment: In you webViewController header, just add the method we created : `-(void)loadWebView:(int)htmlNum;`  The `ActionButton` method takes as a parameter a button (the sender). When you create your buttons, assign a `tag` to them, containing the number of the html they should open

Comment: Without seeing all your code, I can't help you anymore... Instantiate your webViewController somewhere (probably in your `viewDidLoad` method), declare it as a property in your header (if needed) and so on

Comment: or if you are in the webViewController class, you just need to call `[self loadWebView:sender.tag]` in the `ActionButton` method

Comment: how to tell sender.tag that which html is loading?

Comment: thanks my UIWebViewController is fixed just how to add html page number to my tags??

Comment: The `tag` property is a `NSInteger`. So, when you create your button, you set this property to 1, 2,... E.g : `UIButton *button1 = [[UIButton alloc] init]; button1.tag = 1` And you do the same for each button

Comment: I know this for buttons I mean I have different html file how to load them ?